# AllowsTransparency property causes unhandled exception

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new WPF project
2. Set `AllowsTransparency="True"` to the `Window`
3. Run
4. Look at the system logs

In my case on both windows 7 PCs I have in logs:

```
Application: WpfApplication1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Window.VerifyConsistencyWithAllowsTransparency(System.Windows.WindowStyle)
   at System.Windows.Window.CoerceVisibility(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProcessCoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EntryIndex ByRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, System.Object ByRef, System.Object, System.Object, System.Windows.CoerceValueCallback, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.set_Visibility(System.Windows.Visibility)
   at System.Windows.Application.ConfigAppWindowAndRootElement(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfApplication1.App.Main()
```

Can anyone confirm it?

Software I use: VS 2010 Express (SP1), Windows 7 home premium.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a bug report for MSDN? :)

Comment: @BoltClock: I need to check if it is not my local problem or lack of some secret knowledge at first ;-)

Comment: We have almost the same specs, and i try it with your steps, i have the same error that you had.  [VS 2010 Ultimate (SP1) Win 7 Ultimate]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just the change the

WindowStyle="None"

Comment: +1 And in the future the OP should just run it under the debugger and read the message on the screen.  :-)

Comment: So it is expected that changing of one window property without another will cause exception?!

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: Omg, feeling so dummy :-S

Comment: @zerkms: That's what the docs says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx

Comment: @zerkms: Isn't it frustrating that the exception message, the **good** info, isn't in the system log...

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: yes, 1) rtfm 2) run in debug mode 3) ask question at SO. In this particular order. ;-)