# How to fix this "System.InvalidOperationException" Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I want to make a window without border so I put `AllowsTransparency="True"` but when I want to launch my program I get this exception, System.InvalidOperationException

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> WindowStyle.None is the only valid value for WindowStyle when AllowsTransparency is true.

Can you please help me to fix that?

Comment: I would suggest setting `AllowsTransparency` to true.

Comment: Of course :) And a lot of down votes :/

Comment: I would imagine you're being downvoted because this is a clear case of doing absolutely no research, and simply copy + pasting an error here, rather than reading the error.

Comment: Sadly, you are right I should use my brain or use google before doing something like that...

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932704/allowstransparency-property-causes-unhandled-exception

Answer (score 0):

check these settings in your applications:

> when AllowsTransparency is set to true, a window's WindowStyle
>   property must be set to None.

refer this msdn link for more info.

[MSDN AllowsTransparency Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency(v=vs.110).aspx)